# Trying to send an email from Ubuntu 14.04 to yahoo smtp

Tags: email

Trying to send an email from Ubuntu 14.04 to yahoo smtp.

My ip address at home changes and I would like to know it during the day. I was just using `wget http://wtfismyip.com/text` and then I want to email the result of that to myself.

I get this error after running `ssmtp me@yahoo.com < text`:

```
ssmtp: 553 From address not verified - see
http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html
```

I looked at the webpage but it doesn't help.

Here is my `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
mailhub=smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587

FromLineOverride=YES

hostname=localhost

rewriteDomain=yahoo.com

root=me@yahoo.com

UseTLS=YES

AuthMethod=LOGIN

AuthUser=me@yahoo.com

AuthPass=xxxxxx

UseSTARTTLS=Yes

TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Maybe there is a command line that does it? It can be done in cygwin like so:

```
email -V -f me@yahoo.com -s "subject" -r smtp.mail.yahoo.com -p 587 -tls -m login -u me@yahoo.com -i pa$$w0rd me@yahoo.com < email.txt
```

Comment: try with this `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465`

Comment: 465 didn't work for me

Comment: I think it doesn't send attached file.

Comment: Can't get above to work(would still like an answer), but this seems to work: sendemail -f me@yahoo.com -t me@yahoo.com -u currentip -m $myip -s smtp.mail.yahoo.com -o tls=yes -xu $myyahoousername -xp $mypassword

Answer (score 1):

You also need to edit sSMTP aliases **/etc/ssmtp/revaliases**
e.g. `sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/revaliases`
in this case I have set up an alias for *users* **pi** and **motion**

```
# Format:       local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
#
pi:YOURNAME@yahoo.com:smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587
motion:YOURNAME@yahoo.com:smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587
```

===

my configuration for `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=YOURNAME@yahoo.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=yahoo.com

# The full hostname
hostname=YOURNAME@yahoo.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=No

AuthUser=YOURNAME@yahoo.com
AuthPass=YOURPASSWORD
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

===

> Source: 
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmailAlerts